# Shorter way to update object properties in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, destructuring, spread

I have a list of user submissions on different questions and whenever it is being updated, I have several properties I'm updating. I'm wondering if there is a better way perhaps by destructing or spreading to make this cleaner/shorter? Here's what I'm doing at the moment, I've lessened the number of properties in the example, but in the actual project I am updating around 5-6 properties one by one and I felt it is a little repetitive to set it one by one.

```
updateSubmission ( id, type, value ) {
  const obj = state.submission.filter( el => el.id === id )[ 0 ]
  obj.type = type
  obj.value = value
}
```

Comment: Working code should go on the codereview site, afaik.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.find` to find the single matching object instead of `.filter`, then you can `Object.assign` both properties with shorthand:

```
updateSubmission ( id, type, value ) {
  Object.assign(
    state.submission.find( el => el.id === id ),
    { type, value }
  );
}
```

Comment: Yes, use find to get 1, and filter to get many. I wouldn't use Object.assign but spread.

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa spread syntax can't be used to add/update properties in an _existing_ object - you will have to create a new object. `Object.assign` seems more appropriate in this case.

Comment: is there a reason why you would want the existing object when doing a `POST` request ?

Answer (score 1):

If you can change the signature of `updateSubmission` then you can also make the code more generic.

```
updateSubmission ({ id, ...rest }) {
  let obj = state.submission.find( el => el.id === id );
  obj = { ...obj, ...rest };
}
```

**Usage:**

```
updateSubmission({id:'123', type:'abc', value:'xyz'})
```

**Future Benefit:**

1. If tomorrow, the sequence of params changes? then the code works without changing signature.
2. It doesn't matter how many argument you had earlier, with object destructuring, the code works without adding arguments to signature.